# editing an item in different view doesn't update in original view

Tags: knockout.js

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HCQAd/

```
var Editor = function(v1){
    var self = this;
    self.load_editor = function(item){
        item.prop = "Test4";
    }
}

var sectionView = function(){
    var self = this;      
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.load_items = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var items = [{prop:'Test'}, {prop:'Test2'}, {prop:'Test3'}];
            self.items(items);
        }, 500);
    };        
    self.edit_item = function(item)
    {
        if(self.editor == null)
        {
            self.editor = new Editor(self);
            self.editor.load_editor(item);
        }            
    }
    ko.applyBindings(self, $('.items_container')[0]);
}

var v1 = new sectionView();
v1.load_items();



<div class="items_container">
   <!-- ko foreach: items -->
    <span data-bind="text: prop"></span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: $parent.edit_item">edit</a>
    <br/>
       <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Clicking the edit link loads the editor and passes the item being edited. When I set the property to a new value, it doesn't update the original view? How do I make it update in the original view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use observables instead of plain properties.

Your sample with observables:
http://jsfiddle.net/HCQAd/1/

Article about knockout observables and 2-way data-binding.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html